# Larave 6 l “Creating default object from empty value”

Tags: laravel, controller, edit

Here, I have setuo CRUD table with laravel, vuetify and vue . I could successfull create and read data from the database. But, for some reason my update and delete are not working. I am getting error like:

{message: "Creating default object from empty value", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\WinNMP\WWW\chillibiz\app\Sys\Http\Controllers\StageController.php"
line: 53
message: "Creating default object from empty value"
trace: [{file: "C:\WinNMP\WWW\chillibiz\app\Sys\Http\Controllers\StageController.php", line: 53,…},…]

My code are here:

StageController.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Sys\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

use App\Sys\Model\Stage;

class StageController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {  
        $per_page = $request->per_page ? $request->per_page : 5;
        $sort_by = $request->sort_by;
        $order_by = $request->order_by;
        return response()->json(['stages' => Stage::orderBy($sort_by, $order_by)->paginate($per_page)],200);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
        $stage= Stage::create([
            'id' => $uuid,
            'code' =>$request->code,
            'name' =>$request->name,
            'description' =>$request->description,
        ]);
        return response()->json(['stage'=>$stage],200);
    }


    public function show($id)                                                                                                                                                           
    {
        $stages = Stage::where('code','LIKE', "%$id%")->orWhere('name','LIKE', "%$id%")->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%$id%")->paginate();
        return response()->json(['stages' => $stages],200);
    }



    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {


       $stage = Stage::find($id);


       $stage->code  = $request->code; //line 53
       $stage->name  = $request->name;
       $stage->description  = $request->description;


       $stage->save(); 
       return response()->json(['stage'=>$stage], 200);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $stage = Stage::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return  response()->json(['stage'=> $stage],200);
    }



    public function deleteAll(Request $request){
        Stage::whereIn('id', $request->stages)->delete();
        return response()->json(['message', 'Records Deleted Successfully'], 200);
    }
}
```

Stage.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Sys\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stage extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found they you are using uuid as id not increment. that why you get error like that:

to solve your problem you need to add the field to your model;

```
<?php

namespace App\Sys\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stage extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $guarded = [];

}
```

I hope this time you can solve your problem. happy coding.
Edit you can read [docs for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent)